# When the net force is zero, the torque is independent of origin

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, torque, dipole-moment

What does this mean in case of a permanent dipole in a uniform electric field?

Comment: No net force and a torque due to a couple unless the dipole is aligned with the electric field.

Comment: -1. Unclear. Please provide more explanation about your difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you can choose any point, O, and calculate the torque about O on the positive charge. Then calculate the torque about O on the negative charge. Then add the two torques, taking account of their senses (or their directions, if representing them by vectors). You should find that the resultant torque is $qd\ \text{sin}\ \theta$ in which $d$ is the separation of the charges and independent of your choice of O.